# Trying to dynamically add a FormPanel and getting an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to dynamically add a form panel on a button click. I am getting these error messages and I am unsure why it's happening. FYI line 101 is the doLayout() call. Here's the error message:

```
ext-all.js:133 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at Ext.form.BasicForm.initEl (ext-all.js:133)
    at sb.onRender (ext-all.js:134)
    at sb.render (ext-all.js:58)
    at sb.render (ext-all.js:64)
    at Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.renderItem (ext-all.js:65)
    at Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.renderAll (ext-all.js:65)
    at Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.onLayout (ext-all.js:65)
    at Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.layout (ext-all.js:65)
    at sb.doLayout (ext-all.js:64)
    at sb.handler (rcm.js:101)
```

Here's my code:

```
var fieldCount = 0;

var poolPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'poolPanel', width: '99%', frame: false
});

var addSearchField = new Ext.Button({
    id: 'addSearchField', text: "Add Another Search Field", style: 'margin: 1px 0px 5px 5px ',
    handler : function () {
            var spotifyRecordCompanies = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                id: 'searchBar' + fieldCount,
                items: []
            });
            fieldCount++;
            Ext.getCmp("poolPanel").insert(fieldCount, spotifyRecordCompanies);
            Ext.getCmp("poolPanel").doLayout();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've figured it out.

The viewport wasn't configured properly and I just needed to implement it.

The issue had nothing to do with line 101, that's just the place that I was getting the error which is what confused me.